# Create animation from many animation clips

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am working on a `Unity` project where i want to show a car coming out from a garage and travel around the house.
so i created `Animation Clips` of the door opens, car driving around the house and some others.
lets call them animations a, b, c.

now i want to make this animation run in sequence,in this order a -> b -> c.

how can i managed this?
a method without writing scripts is preffered.
good reference will also be great! im kind a new to unity, know key framing aninations. wanted to beleive that there is an easy way to make it trough.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an [animation event](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html) at the end of your animations playing the next animation. This would require a script, but a very simple one. Add the name of the animation in the event, so it's reusable.

Answer (score 0):

I think without scripting you can't solve you problem so you can look this link or ask someone write your code

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html
https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/animation